# Cocos2d-x OS X application menus

Tags: xcode, macos, cocoa, menu, cocos2d-x

I have a cocos2d-x application that I have been mostly debugging on iOS.  Now I am working on the OS X side of things.

As expected, everything works pretty much the same, except that I have some gesture commands in my iOS app that do not translate to OS X.

I would like to create menu items (OS X level) and associated shortcuts to accomplish some of the gesture interactions (at least as one option).

Creating a MainMenu.xib and linking it in the project settings doesn't seem to be the whole story.  The menus are still the generic "AppName" and Window menus, and not the ones I created in the xib file.

I believe I need to wire it up to the AppDelegate somehow, but I'm not sure how, and I haven't had any success finding documentation to that effect, at least in relation to how it interplays with Cocos2d-x.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Essentially you just need to create the menu in an Objective-C++ class that you call from AppDelegate.cpp or wherever. The extension will be `.mm` in order to invoke the objective-c compiler/runtime. You can then create the NSMenu and add items or replace an entire menu set[ServiceMenu/WindowMenu/MainMenu]

NSMenu reference: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSMenu_Class/index.html)

I found the only interesting part was receiving an action from the menu where I believe you need to then also create an objective-c class as the receiver (target).

You should be able to load the .xib file in as a entirely new menu to replace the one GLFW3 creates, but I haven't looked into that yet.

**Update:** Here's an example project.

https://github.com/stevetranby/TestNSMenuCocos2Dx

**Update:** Added example to project for loading the menu with .xib